# Why does not the try/catch in java work on my case?

Tags: java, selenium, try-catch

I have written a try/catch block on java selenium and I do not understand why it does not function. It is supposed to check for a web element on the webpage and if it does not find it should throw a NoSuchElementException and go to the catch block.What really happens is that the element is not found and the execution does not continue to catch block,it fails the test(Selenium WebTest) and stops the execution completely,failing my test.I have also included "throws NoSuchElementException" in the main method. Here is some code for reference. What can the problem be? How can I write a failproof code?

```
 try {
// this is the web element to be found by xpath,sometimes it is on the webpage,sometimes not

can = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"revealGameAnimation\"]/canvas"));
}

catch(NoSuchElementException e)
{

// some code here

}
```

Comment: you could catch Exception e and then print out the class of the exception to find out why your catch does not work e.getClass()

Comment: Please always show the full error in the question. From a [comment you wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68128119/why-does-not-the-try-catch-in-java-work-on-my-case#comment120411555_68128171) to an answer, it appears that the error you get is `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`, and I'll bet that you incorrectly imported `java.util.NoSuchElementException`, which is why it's not catching the actual thrown exception.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Can someone show me correctly how to include source code in the question in the right way? I am new to StackOverflow and I haven't understood yet how it works with adding questions with code and so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because Selenium throws `ElementNotFoundException` exception in such case.

Comment: It throws "NoSuchElementException". Read carefully my question. I have the error log here after running the test. Check the error here "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="revealGameAnimation"]/canvas"}".

Comment: @Erli Are you sure your code imported `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`, and not e.g. `java.util.NoSuchElementException`?